# js Promise, cancel timeout

Tags: javascript, promise, cancellation

currently I am using a script to set a timeout of 3 seconds for my function before the next action is executed.

```
function sleep(ms)
{
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

sleep(3000).then(function()
{
    // next action
});
```

Now I want to find a way to end the 3-second timeout early e.g. by performing a mouse click. How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using Promises for this? Promises are great, but they aren't cancellable. And `setTimeout` returns an ID you can use to cancel the impending function call.

Comment: you need to clear the timeout then call the resolver if you want or just move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```js
function sleeper(ms) {
  var r;

  var p = new Promise(resolve => {
    r = resolve;
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });

  return {
    skip: r,
    promise: p
  };
}

var s = sleeper(10000);

s.promise.then(() => {
  console.log('Promise finished!');
});

console.log('Waiting for 10 seconds... Click the button to skip the wait.');

document.getElementById('skip').addEventListener('click', s.skip);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="skip" value="Skip delay" />
```

Comment: s2 promise will be resolved even though you skipped it because you didn't canceled the timeout of it

Comment: @Dabbas It's supposed to be resolved. I don't think there's a problem here.

Comment: in the previous code (before editing) the second promise called even though I skipped it and didn't called it again.

Comment: @Dabbas There were two promises in the previous version of my code. That's why two promises were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea maybe you can do this:

```
var timeout, myResolver;
function sleep(ms)
{
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
            myResolver = resolve;
            timeout = setTimeout(resolve, ms);
       });
}

sleep(3000).then(function()
{
    // next action
});
function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    myResolver();
}
```